# Removing parts of a string from data frame rows in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data frame column with a string followed by a decimal and a number (e.g., 
`data <- data.frame(ID = c("alpha.1","alpha.2", "alpha.3", "beta.1", "beta.2", "beta.3"))`. How can I remove just the decimal and the number, and leave the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the `.` followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$)` of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

```
data$ID <- sub("\\.\\d+$", "", data$ID)
data$ID
#[1] "alpha" "alpha" "alpha" "beta"  "beta"  "beta"
```

---

Or another option is `trimws`

```
data$ID <- trimws(data$ID, whitespace = "\\..*")
```

---

Or using `word`

```
library(stringr)
word(data$ID, 1, sep=fixed("."))
#[1] "alpha" "alpha" "alpha" "beta"  "beta"  "beta"
```